# In R, how to replace values in a column with values of another column of another data set based on a condition?

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have to data sets, samples of which I've given below. I need to replace project names in `target_df$project_name`, in case they are present in `registry_df$to_change` with corresponding values in `registry_df$replacement`. However, the code I tried, obviously, did not deliver any result. How should it be corrected or what other way there is to achieve the desired goal?

Data sets:

```
target_df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~project_name,     ~sum,   
  "Mark",            "4307",     
  "Boat",            "9567",       
  "Delorean",        "5344",      
  "Parix",           "1043",
)

registry_df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~to_change,     ~replacement,   
  "Mark",            "Duck",     
  "Boat",            "Tank",       
  "Toloune",         "Bordeaux",      
  "Hunge",           "Juron",
)
```

Desired output of target_df :

```
project_name        sum   
  "Duck"            "4307"     
  "Tank"            "9567"       
  "Delorean"        "5344"      
  "Parix"           "1043"
```

Code:

```
library(data.table)

target_df <- transform(target_df, 
                       project_name = ifelse(target_df$project_name %in% registry_df$to_change),
                       registry_df$replacement,
                       project_name
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution. There's probably an elegant way with less steps.

```
library(dplyr)

target_df <- target_df %>% 
  left_join(registry_df,  
            by = c("project_name" = "to_change")) %>% 
  mutate(replacement = ifelse(is.na(replacement), project_name, replacement)) %>% 
  select(project_name = replacement, sum)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  project_name sum  
  <chr>        <chr>
1 Duck         4307 
2 Tank         9567 
3 Delorean     5344 
4 Parix        1043
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R solution: You can match the columns using the `match` function. Since not all levels of `target_df$project_name` are in `registry_df$to_change` your matching variable will have `NA`s. Therefor, I included the `ifelse` function which in case of `NA`s keeps original values.

```
matching <- registry_df$replacement[match(target_df$project_name, registry_df$to_change)]
target_df$project_name <- ifelse(is.na(matching),
                                 target_df$project_name,
                                 matching)
```

`target_df` gives expected output:

```
  project_name sum  
  <chr>        <chr>
1 Duck         4307 
2 Tank         9567 
3 Delorean     5344 
4 Parix        1043
```